# Print last field in file and use it for name of another file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, awk, grep

I have a tab delimited file with 3 rows and 7 columns.  I want to use the number at the end of the file to rename another file.

Example of tab delimited file:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   b   c   d   e   f   1235
```

So, I want to extract the number from tab delimited file and then rename "file1" to the number extracted (`mv file1 1235`)

I can print the column, but I cannot seem to extract just the number from the file. Even if I can extract the number I can't seem to figure out how to store that number to use as the new file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something along these lines perhaps?

```
num=$(tail -1 file1 | rev | awk '{print $1}' | rev)
mv file1 $num
```

Comment: You can use the variable `NF` to get the last field.

Comment: Using `awk` you can do `awk 'END{print $NF > $NF}' file` or if the file is too big then, `tac file | awk '{print $NF > $NF;exit}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`

```
name=$(awk 'END {print $NF}' file)
mv file $name
```

Comment: @MohitJain The `END` section is only run after last line, so the last field `$NF` then holds the last data from the last line.  This is stored to a variable `name`.  Then renaming the file using `mv` to the name in variable `name`

Comment: Just be aware that not all awks will still have $NF populated in the END section.

Comment: @EdMorton In that case you can use `awk '{f=$NF} END {print f}'`

Comment: Welllll - TECHNICALLY it should be `awk '{f=$NF ORS} END {printf "%s",f}'` so it doesn't print a blank line if the input file is empty but I don't suppose that'll matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{($f) = @ARGV} ($n) = /(\d+)$/; END{rename($f, $n)}' file1
```